# MousePicking in LWJGL - How to do it?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, raycasting

I have been working on a mouse picker for a scene in 3d for a client, and been having issues implementing a proper mouse pick. His application does not use a camera, and I am trying to get the ray from the flat Display.

What is supposed to happen: Right click mouse, picked creates ray from mouse point to back of display.

```
/*
private Vector3f currentRay = new Vector3f();;

private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;
private Matrix4f viewMatrix;
private Camera cam;

private Vector3f currentWorldPoint;

public Picker(Camera cam, Matrix4f projection) {
    this.cam = cam;
    projectionMatrix = projection;
    viewMatrix = Camera.createViewMatrix(this.cam);
}

public Vector3f getMousePosition() {
    return currentWorldPoint;
}

// Returns the currentRay
public Vector3f getCurrentRay() {
    return currentRay;
}

public void update(Camera cam) {
    viewMatrix = Camera.createViewMatrix(cam);
    currentRay = calculateMouseRay();
}

// Takes the X Y of the mouse POS and changes it from Normalize > Clip > Eye > World coordinates of the screen.
// Returns the world coordinates of the ray
private Vector3f calculateMouseRay() {
    float mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    float mouseY = Mouse.getY();
    Vector2f normalizedCoords = getNormalizedDeviceCoords(mouseX, mouseY);
    Vector4f clipCoords = new Vector4f(normalizedCoords.x, normalizedCoords.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector4f eyeCoords = toEyeCoords(clipCoords);
    Vector3f worldRay = toWorldCoords(eyeCoords);
    return worldRay;
}

// Takes in the floats of the X Y of mouse, returns the X Y according to the normalized coordinates.
private Vector2f getNormalizedDeviceCoords(float mouseX, float mouseY) {
    float x = (2f*mouseX) / Display.getWidth() - 1;
    float y = (2f * mouseY) / Display.getHeight() - 1f;
    return new Vector2f(x, y);
}

// Takes in the eye coordinates of the mouse location, returns the world coordinates.
private Vector3f toWorldCoords(Vector4f eyeCoords) {
    Matrix4f invertedView = Matrix4f.invert(viewMatrix,  null);
    Vector4f rayWorld = Matrix4f.transform(invertedView, eyeCoords, null);
    Vector3f mouseRay = new Vector3f(rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z);
    mouseRay.normalise();
    return mouseRay;
}

// Takes in the clip coordinates of the mouse, returns them in eye coordinates
private Vector4f toEyeCoords(Vector4f clipCoords) {
    Matrix4f invertedProjection = Matrix4f.invert(projectionMatrix, null);
    Vector4f eyeCoords = Matrix4f.transform(invertedProjection, clipCoords, null);
    return new Vector4f(eyeCoords.x, eyeCoords.y, -1f, 0f);
}

private Vector3f getPointOnRay(Vector3f ray, float distance) {
    Vector3f camPos = cam.getPosition();
    Vector3f start = new Vector3f(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
    Vector3f scaledRay = new Vector3f(ray.z * distance, ray.y * distance, ray.z * distance);
    return Vector3f.add(start,  scaledRay,  null);
}
*/

static Vector3f startRay;
static Vector3f endRay;

public Picker() {
    startRay = new Vector3f();
    endRay = new Vector3f();
}

private static Vector2f getMouseCoords() {
    float x = (2f* Mouse.getX()) / Display.getWidth() - 1;
    float y = (2f * Mouse.getY()) / Display.getHeight() - 1f;
    return new Vector2f(x, y);
}

private Vector3f calculateMouseRay() {
    float mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    float mouseY = Mouse.getY();
    Vector2f normalizedCoords = getMouseCoords();
    Vector4f clipCoords = new Vector4f(normalizedCoords.x, normalizedCoords.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector4f eyeCoords = toEyeCoords(clipCoords);
    Vector3f worldRay = toWorldCoords(eyeCoords);
    return worldRay;
}

public static String getRayStr() {
    float x = (2f* Mouse.getX()) / Display.getWidth() - 1;
    float y = (2f * Mouse.getY()) / Display.getHeight() - 1f;
    String str = "Mouse X: " + x + " Mouse Y: " + y;
    str += "\nStart X: " + startRay.x + " Start Y: " + startRay.y + " Start Z: " + startRay.z; 
    str += "\nEnd X: " + endRay.x + " End Y: " + endRay.y + " End Z: " + endRay.z; 
    return str;
}

public static void setStartRay() {
    Vector2f mousePos = getMouseCoords();
    Vector3f tempStartPos = new Vector3f();
    tempStartPos.x = mousePos.x;
    tempStartPos.y = mousePos.y;
    tempStartPos.z = 0;

    startRay = tempStartPos;
}

public static void setEndRay() {
    Vector2f mousePos = getMouseCoords();
    Vector3f tempEndPos = new Vector3f();
    tempEndPos.x = mousePos.x;
    tempEndPos.y = mousePos.y;
    tempEndPos.z = -1;

    endRay = tempEndPos;
}

public static Vector3f getStartRay() {
    return startRay;
}

public static Vector3f getEndRay() {
    return endRay;
}
```

Comment: How do the results you get differ from the desired behaviour? What is the significance of the code you've commented-out?

Comment: @DMGregory I was trying to follow a tutorial on YouTube, but the tutorial used from a camera viewpoint to create matrices. Where I am just trying to draw from mouse point over the display straight back to the end of the display. Right now it doesn't create a ray that can detect objects, and I am not really sure how to implement it.